# Radio antenna for my FM receiver / Android FM

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, receiver, fm

I want to make a radio antenna at home which will be able to receive all FM frequencies for my FM radio or Android FM.
How do I make it?

Frequency it can catch : 88 - 108 MHz

Thanks.

Comment: FM is a modulation mode. I'm assuming you mean something on the 2m or 70cm bands where that mode is most common? Check out this link and see if it helps: https://hamradioschool.com/considering-a-vhfuhf-antenna-for-your-home/

Comment: What do the antenna inputs look like? I assume that there is a place to plug in an antenna?

Comment: We need more information. I think that Mike is correct that we are talking about 88-108MHz, but unless we know what connectors are needed, and whether the input is balanced or unbalanced (two screws, or a regular coax socket), and whether the antenna is going to be indoors or outdoors, it would be difficult to give a useful answer.

Comment: I need 88 - 108 MHz FM receiver antenna

Comment: To paraphrase what Scott said, **Unless we know what connectors are needed, and whether your radio inputs are balanced or unbalanced (two screws, or a regular coax socket), and whether the antenna is going to be indoors or outdoors, it will be impossible to give you a useful answer**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common receiver antennas for the FM broadcast band (88-108 MHz) are typically center-fed folded dipoles roundly 1.5 meters long (half wavelength for the ~100 MHz center frequency of the band); they're made from twin-lead (flat, like old fashioned TV antenna cable) cut to length, conductors joined at the ends, and one conductor cut at the center and joined to a similar length of twin-lead feed line -- at DC, this forms a simple loop.  In practice, a long wire, up to about ten wavelengths (thirty meters) will do at least as well, but isn't as compatible with an indoor installation.

Adding an antenna to an Android device, however, isn't as simple as hooking up a wire antenna.  Most such devices have no provision for an external antenna, or any connector for one (in a phone designed more than five years ago or so) is likely to be hidden inside the back cover of the device.  Many modern Android devices use fractal antennas to give the effect of a resonant antenna for the cellular communication frequency (much higher than FM broadcast, though it varies by phone make/model and cell provider), and some of the more popular current models have deleted the FM radio receive capability in hardware (my first-gen Pixel, for instance, lacks the FM chip).

Comment: My new Samsung Android 8 smartphone has the capability of receiving FM BC. The earbud leads act as the antenna.

Comment: I want indoor dude

Comment: My last phone, a Galaxy S4, had the chip but my carrier never unlocked FM receive on the versions of Android I was able to get, and I replaced it before I got fed up enough to root it.

Comment: You said, "Many modern Android devices use fractal antennas..."  Was it [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_carpet), do know? How did you learn about that? Thanks.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I saw photos and an article somewhere several years ago, not long after the external antennas disappeared from cell phones (early 2000s?).  IIRC, it was more of a triangular Sierpinski gasket than the square carpet you linked.

Comment: Thank you for that info...